# How to configure OSGI Declarative Service scope?

Tags: java, osgi, declarative-services

Can someone please explain me how to configure OSGI DS to be a singleton? 
I use Equinox as OSGi container.

#### SCR component

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<scr:component xmlns:scr="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/scr/v1.1.0" name="Simple Dictionary">
   <implementation class="foo.bar.services.DictionaryImpl"/>
   <service>
      <provide interface="foo.bar.services.Dictionary"/>
   </service>
</scr:component>
```

#### OSGI console output

**osgi>** services (objectClass=foo.bar.services*)
{foo.bar.services.Dictionary}={
component.name=Simple Dictionary,
component.id=0,
 
service.id=51,
service.bundleid=7,
 
**service.scope=bundle**
}
  "Registered by bundle:" foo.bar.services_1.0.0.qualifier [7]
  "No bundles using service."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a singleton unless you say `servicefactory="true"`. DS will always use a SerivceFactory to register the service of the component. This allows the actual component creation and activation to be lazy. So you will never see service.scope=singleton on the registered service.

For DS 1.3, `servicefactory` will be replaced by `scope` but the above statement about DS always using a ServiceFactory is still true.

Comment: Does latest version of apache felix support DS 1.3? As I see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSGi_Specification_Implementations#112:_Declarative_Services it does. But I can't find information how to use scopes.